# Asus 1215n GPU driver/s don't give me a "full" OS experience

Tags: graphics, webgl, nvidia-optimus, html5

I'm use to not having specific drivers from a manufacture on my laptop when running a Linux OS and that has always been fine - there's been adequate FOSS drivers for my needs and it hasn't ruined any of my OS experience.

When I bought an Asus 1215n one of the upsides to the hardware seemed to be the switchable GPU that could give lots of performance or lots more battery life and would switch on-the-fly... with Windows of course.

Seems that the Nvidia driver are crap and people advise not installing them. I have some sort of workaround for vga_switcharoo (?) and the on-the-fly nature of the GPUs has turned in to a manual one :(

The worst bit though (aside from shorter battery life) is the web experience with HTML5. If I visit Mozilla's Web O'Wonder site I'm told I don't have WebGL working due to driver issues.

This really blows - is it possible that proprietary drivers can now ruin my web experience too?!

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of successful reports for the Asus 1215N with bumblebee. You can use the nvidia card for chrome or any other application you use to, and leave the desktop to run under the Intel card. Have a look here:
https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux

The bumblebee-disablecard.1215n and bumblebee-enablecard.1215n files will switch on/off the card on demand.